# What is domain.actdsltmp?

Tags: domain-name-system, readynas

In my ReadyNAS, the DNS "Domain name" is set to domain.actdsltmp. I don't know how it got that way or what it means, and searching reveals lots of mentions but no explanation I could find.

Does this mean something to someone?

Comment: Given locations you find [actdsltmp](http://www.google.com/search?q=actdsltmp) I would guess that is poor default on crappy consumer router/device firmware.

Comment: @Zoredache totally bit your comment-answer. =P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely have a cheap modem / router unit that is set to have domain.actdsltmp as the default domain. I wouldn't be surprised if there's some device by Actiontec on the network. Look in the firmware of your modem / router and replace it with a domain.tld that fits your scenario.